# Error (Xcode): 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found /Users/macbook/Developer/RobyHub/mobile/admin-app/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h:9:8

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, build

```
Error (Xcode): 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
/Users/macbook/Developer/RobyHub/mobile/admin-app/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h:9:8
```

```
Error (Xcode): failed to emit precompiled header
'/Users/macbook/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-cnmmmgwjwyedhrfbmwidyiqajgcy/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledH
eaders/Runner-Bridging-Header-swift_21KKX35XMXJF3-clang_2DSDA8C9CPQUA.pch' for bridging header
'/Users/macbook/Developer/RobyHub/mobile/admin-app/ios/Runner/Runner-Bridging-Header.h'


    Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.8, on macOS 13.0 22A380 darwin-x64, locale en-US)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.73.1)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability



Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 14 Pro.
```

I started encoutering these errors, ever since i archived my application and uploaded it on my apple store connect, the reaseon i decided to build again was just to screenshot screen of my applications for review on my app store connect.

I validated and distributed my app without any furtheer issues.

Any solution would be appreeciated, please

I've tried everything from

flutter clean
pod install
i've deleted the pod file and lock file
Done pod update
flutter run

Tried these several times, my issue still persists.

Comment: You have to clean the flutter and install the pod again.

Answer (score 0):

After attempting several fixes, what solved this for me was by restarting my pc

First make sure to close your xcode or visual studio

Upon restart completion, open VScode again, then open terminal in vscode and cd to ios folder on your flutter application code, and run the following:

```
pod cache clean --all
```

after which run:

```
pod install
```

Once completed go back to your main flutter directory using

```
cd ../
```

Then run:

```
flutter build ios
flutter run
```